# Code added to App_Code isn't available in the rest of my solution, why?

Tags: asp.net, .net, reporting-services, app-code

Like the Title states,  I added code to an App_Code folder that I created so I could reference it in the rest of the Web App but it is not happening and I'm not sure why.

I have tried using no namespace, the same namespace as the rest of the web app, and giving it it's own namespace.

FWIW, I am trying to use this [Aspnet - SSRS](https://github.com/dotnetcurry/aspnet-ssrs) in my Webapp and basically following the directions provided for it here [Integrating ASP.NET and SSRS](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=844)

My WebApp is on .Net 4.5.1

### EDIT

So, I followed the advice posted below and removed the App_Code folder and created an SSRS folder where I placed all 4 files referenced in the Git Repo.  I'm REALLY confused now as it still tells me that there isn't a namespace for SSRS or MyProject.SSRS.

Is there something special about those files?  They just look like class files to me.  2 of them are Proxy Classes for `ReportExecutionService` & `ReportingService2010`

Is there something else I can look at?

Comment: Ignore my last, I'm an idiot...somehow they were set to Content not Compile.  Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.co.uk/2009/07/appcode-folder-doesnt-work-with-web.html) article explains why it's like that.

To keep your 'normal' code that you want to use in your app create normal folder and name it e.g. SSRS.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that and apparently misunderstood or was mislead by that article that I posted.  I give this a shot.

Comment: You should add a brief summary of the article into your answer. That way if the link ever "rots" then your answer will still contain useful information.

Comment: @mason Good idea, will do!